# Mark start and end of a sequence of objects in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

I have a list of objects. I am looking to search for a particular pattern amongst the entries in the list with a view to marking the beginning and end when the pattern is encountered.

So for a very simple example, suppose it was a list of strings

a b c a b e d f a b

and a b was the pattern, the list would be transformed into (using ^ as the start marker and # as the end)

^ a b # c ^ a b # e d f ^ a b #

I'm struggling to find a "clean" way to frame/think about the problem. I could do loops within loops, moving through the list comparing the sequence at the current position in the list with the desired sequence, but I'm wondering if there is a less procedural alternative - hence my specifying LINQ which tends, in my experience, to require a different, perhaps more FP, mindset.

Is there an algorithm or a generic approach which does something like this sort of thing?

NOTE 1 - I am **NOT** looking for string pattern matching but rather marking sequences of a pattern of objects  within a larger list. So, for example, the list could contain objects, and I would want to mark where specified sequences of object hashes occur within the list.

NOTE 2 - the pattern to identify could be formed by a variable number of objects

NOTE 3 - I am looking to retain the order of the original list within the  transformed and marked list

Comment: 1) What if the pattern was `a b` and the sequence was `a c d b`? 2) What if the pattern was `a b` and the sequence was `a b b`?

Comment: Thx. 1) no markers 2) ^ a b # b. The pattern is a "strict" sequence, if you will.

Comment: How complex could the pattern be? is it a simple list of objects?

Comment: Yes, in the first instance. It is like the pattern forms the size of the window as you watch the list scroll past! (I'm obviously struggling for metaphors!!)

Comment: So I've just come across the Sliding Window Algorithm, which looks promising.

Comment: Can the pattern overlap itself, this is bad description of what I'm asking so let me give you an example. Can the pattern be `a a b`? The reason I ask this is that if the answer is *no*, then I think it would be easy to handle it, but if it can overlap I think perhaps an algorithm such as [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string-search_algorithm) would be appropriate. Boyer-Moore handles cases where, when you discover that the pattern (or word as this one is interested in) isn't fully present, you might have to backtrace to find a new starting point.

Comment: Yes. (I hope I'm understanding you correctly.) a a b would be fine as a pattern. e.g. a b a a b a b b a a b would mark 2 occurrences. a b ^ a a b # a b b ^ a a b # I'll have a look at Boyer-Moore. Thx vm.

Comment: The power of Boyer-Moore comes around when you have the pattern `a a b` and the sequence `a a a b`. If you were to just scan the string for this pattern and do it in a optimal, try to visit the characters as few times as possible, you would be after the first 2 a's when you detected that the pattern didn't match. Boyer-Moore has an efficient method by which it backtracks just one character so that you start at `a >a< a b` for your next comparison. This becomes even more important when the pattern is longer, as the suboptimal method would be to backtrack all the way back and skip the first one.